# File Structure member changed in C

Tags: c, file

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main( )
{
    FILE* fp = stdin;
    printf("Input string: ");
    
    printf("getchar( ) - %c\n", getchar());
    printf("[%d] %s", fp->_cnt, fp->_base);
    printf("READ: %d\n", fp-> _ptr - fp->_base);


    printf("\\n\ngetchar( ) - %c\n", getchar());
    printf("[%d] %s", fp->_cnt, fp->_base);
    printf("READ: %d\n", fp->_ptr - fp->_base);


    fflush(fp);
    printf("\n\nAfter flushing\n[%d] %s", fp->_cnt, fp->_base);
    printf("READ: %d\n", fp->_ptr - fp->_base);
}
```

1. I have this code in my C book, but there is no `_cnt` member in the `FILE` structure.
2. How can I get the right result?

Comment: What would be the right result?

Comment: That would be *bad* C code (and, implicitly, a *bad* book). The `FILE*` type points to an [opaque structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer) and its members should never be explicitly used.

Comment: What is the book, and why is it using internal parts of the `FILE` structure?

Comment: @AdrianMole: If members of the `FILE` structure should never be explicitly used, how can anybody implement the standard I/O functions? Or teach anybody else how to implement them?

Comment: @Eric OK, They should not be used by code outside of the implementation itself. Rather, the standard routines to retrieve information about an open FILE should be used. As you'll no doubt be aware, different implementations can implement the `FILE` structure in different ways, with different names for the members.

Comment: @AdrianMole: Kernighan and Ritchie’s _The C Programming Language_, second edition, shows code using members of the `FILE` structure on page 178, where it is teaching about implementing the library. That does not make it a bad C book.

Comment: @Eric I can't argue with your last sentence, and nor will I attempt to. (I only have the first edition, which I shall check when I get to the lab, later on.)

Comment: I found this code in 'How to flush stdin buffer by using fflush() function' part. So If FILE structure has been changed, fflush() doesn't do anyhing on stdin buffer?

Comment: Then how can I flush stdin buffer? The writer says, 'There are some problems in using stdin buffer like remaining '\n'. We can solve this problem by using fflush().'

Comment: Answer the questions you were asked: What is the book, and why is it using internal parts of the FILE structure? Also state what C implementation you are using. What is the compiler, and what is the C standard library you are using? Did you install the C implementation as some software package or did it come with your operating system? Which system and what version?

Comment: If you just want to remove a newline character from the input, then call `getchar()` until it returns `'\n`' or `EOF`. And, if that is why your book is saying to use internal members of `FILE` in regular software, others may have been right: The book is bad.

Answer (score 1):

The book you are using is paired with a specific implementation of C, possibly one that is quite old. These member names are used in the first edition of Kernighan and Ritchie’s *The C Programming Language*. In the second edition, the underscores were removed. To get this code working as is, you would have to use a matching implementation of C, which may be problematic on modern platforms.

Alternatively, you might be able to get the code working by modifying the member names, if the C implementation you are using has analogous members. However, the code in modern C library headers may be hard for students to understand, as it has grown to accommodate many features and variations for different platforms, complicating it considerably. You may be better off seeking a modern textbook.

Be aware that where the book is showing members of the `FILE` structure, it is likely teaching theory about how the standard library may be implemented or how it operates. It is not showing you code that you should use in regular programs that use the C library.